# How to access object decoded from JSON by cl-json?

Tags: json, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to get JSON import in Common Lisp. I figured out how to decode an object from a JSON string, but I don't know how to access the properties of the object that's returned.   To decode a string (and store the result in ***tempjson**), I do this:

```
(defun test-json ()
 (with-input-from-string
   (s "{\"foo\": [1, 2, 3], \"bar\": true, \"baz\": \"!\"}")
    (defparameter *tempjson* (json:decode-json s))))
```

How can I access ***tempjson*** data. For example, how can I get the value of the **foo** property?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  If you can pass a stream to decode-json, can you not pass it one created by with-open-file?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. I'm trying to get the value of foo after it is decoded. For example, if I were to use a hash table it would be (gethash 'foo *tempjson*) but I don't know the equivalent of that in this case.

Comment: Your question title is "Decoding a JSON File Using cl-json Common Lisp".  It looks like the answer would be something like `(with-open-file (s "some-file") (json:decode-json s))`.  In your question, you said that you "can't seem to access the created JSON File."  What file are you talking about?   `*tempjson*` isn't a file, it's a variable, and you haven't shown us its value.  If you run `test-json` and then evaluate `*tempjson*`, what do you get?

Comment: Based on the answer you accepted and your comments on the question, I've edited the question a bit to reflect what it seems like you're actually trying to do.  Can you take a look and see if it's a suitable description?

Comment: Yeah that is a lot better. Thanks. The answer works well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`decode-json` appears to return an association list (at least in this case; see [documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/)). You can access the values with the function [`assoc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm):

```
(defun test-json ()
  (with-input-from-string (s "{\"foo\": [1, 2, 3], \"bar\": true, \"baz\": \"!\"}")
    (let ((data (json:decode-json s)))
      (format t "~a~%" (rest (assoc :foo data))))))
```

Comment: That works, I didn't know what assoc was and couldn't find it anywhere.